# No idea how to initialize another value to a variable in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
set test=%1

if "%1"=="" (
set test=default
echo %test%
) else (
set test=%1
echo %test%
)
```

Test:

```
test.bat
```

Output:

```
ECHO is off
```

Problem: The 'default' string cannot be assigned as a value to variable 'test'. I've found out that test string's value is still %1 which has no value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the standard batch beginner bug.
Percent expansion doesn't work in parenthesis as you expected.
It expands when the complete block is parsed, before any of the lines are executed.

So `%test%` is expanded to nothing, the value before it enters the block.

The solution is to use delayed expansion here, as `!test!` will be expanded at execution not parse time.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set test=%1

if "%1"=="" (
  set test=default
  echo !test!
) else (
  set test=%1
  echo !test!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realise it worked that way but it appears to be a scoping problem with the value changed in the inner block not being propagated. The following appears to work fine:

```
@echo off

if "%1"=="" (
    set test=default
) else (
    set test=%1
)
echo %test%
```